# How to determine if deadlock is possible, given the number of processes and resources

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

> Consider a system that has three processes and three identical resources. Each process needs a maximum of two resources. Is deadlock possible in this system?

It it my understanding that deadlock is possible if the four conditions hold simultaneously:
Mutual exclusion, hold and wait, no pre-emption, and circular wait.

If each process is allocated one resource, then all three resources will be held. There is no forth resource available.

How do I go about proving that deadlock is not possible, and how would I calculate how many resources should be available to make the system deadlock free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases the trick is to evaluate the **CIRCULAR WAIT** condition and see if it holds or not. 3 Processes and 3 identical resources. Let us give 1 to each of them. **0** resources left, yet no process requirement is complete(*as each needs 2*),which means that **every process is waiting for some other process to release the resources**. Circular wait condition satisfied. Therefore the given scenario **can lead** to deadlock.

Suppose we have **n** processes and **m** identical resources with maximum demands as **d1,d2,d3......dn.**

If **m >** **(d1-1) + (d2-1) + (d3-1)......(dn-1).**, then its **deadlock free**,

otherwise **it can lead to deadlock**

Answer (score 0):

Consider a system with m resources of the same type being shared by n 
processes. Resources can be requested and released by processes only on at a 
time. The system is deadlock free if and only if the sum of all max needs is < m+n.

**For example:**
*A system has 3 processes sharing 4 resources. If each process needs a maximum of 2 units, then:*

To make a system deadlock free, assign each process with one less then their max need. After doing so if we are left with one or more resources then there is no deadlock.

Assign 1 resource (max need -1) to each process.

allocated resources=1+1+1=3

we are still left with 1 resource to avoid deadlock.

so deadlock can never occur.